# Correct use of PhoneGap SSL Certificate Checker plugin

Tags: ssl-certificate, cordova-plugins

Hopefully, as I understood correctly to safely transmit (post) data from a phonegap / cordova hybrid app to a server, I need a procedure to check the SSL certificate of my server. Am I right?

The tool `PhoneGap SSL Certificate Checker plugin` developed by eddyverbruggen (to be found here https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sslcertificatechecker) seems the most user friendly tool available.

However, from the guide, I cannot deduce how to properly use the tool.

- Is it sufficient to call the function `window.plugins.sslCertificateChecker.check` when the app is launched or;
- Do I need to call the function everytime the user wants to post (and retrieve) data to (from) the server; calling the post function (an ajax function) in the `successCallback`?

Thank you

PS. I also encountered the Cordova Advanced HTTP plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-advanced-http) that seems less user friendly to me. I think it is a separate question, but if someone could give a hint about the differences between the two plugins, that would be appreciated too.